# Find all continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $(f(x+y))^2-(f(x-y))^2=4f(x)f(y)$

Tags: functions, continuity, contest-math, functional-equations

I encountered the following question in a math-contest

> Find all  continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$(f(x+y))^2-(f(x-y))^2=4f(x)f(y).$$

I substituted $y$ by $0$ to get that either $f$ is the zero function or the image of $0$ by $f$ is $0$. Now I found one solution (the zero function). Moving to the second case I substituted $y$ by $x$ to get $f(2x)^2=4f(x)^2$. I separated the two subcases: Either $f(2x)=2f(x)$
Or $f(2x)=-2f(x)$. Also flipping $x$ and $y$ gives us the fact that $f$ is an odd function. However I couldn't get any further.
I hope you would like to help me finish the solution of this problem.

Comment: Note that you do not only have two subclasses. For each $x$, we could have $f(2x) = 2f(x) $ or $f(2x) = -2f(x)$. IE we could have $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(4) = - 4, f(8) = 8$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%5E2(x%2By)-f%5E2(x-y)%3D4f(x)f(y)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Acontinuous&p=1), there's the very similar (i.e., it doesn't have the continuous function requirement) AoPS thread [Functional equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1602747p9981987).

Comment: @CalvinLin Keep in mind the question is asking for only *continuous* functions.

Comment: "$f$ is the zero function or the image of $0$ by $f$ is $0$" is equivalent to "$f(0)=0$".

Comment: @JohnOmielan I'm aware. My point is that more work does need to be done than what OP has shown so far. EG We can't eliminate $f(x) = |x|$ as yet (though when we substitute it back in, it doesn't satisfy the equation)

Comment: Yes we can: $f$ is odd.

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm not disagreeing with your statement (which is true). My point is only that going from "$f(2x)^2 = 4f(x)^2$ for each value of $x$ doesn't imply that $f(2x) = 2f(x) \forall x$ or $f(2x) = -2f(x) \forall x$. What we have is $f(2x) = \pm_x 2f(x)$, where the $\pm_x$ indicates it could be $+$ or $-$ for each particular value of $x$.  $\quad$ More work needs to be done, like using continuity that John mentioned, but even then that might not be enough. As an example, $f(x) = |x|$ is continuous and satisfies $f(2x) ^2 = 4f(x)^2$. (and yes it doesn't satisfy the original equation)

Comment: @JohnOmielan Looking at the AOPS site, I don't see a complete solution there. Would you agree? EG mkh's solution ignores the possibility that the only solution to $f(a) = 0 $ is $a= 0 $, which makes the rest useless (and also they don't show true additivity, so I don't know why $f(x+a) = f(x) + f(a) $ matters).

Comment: Seems like a quadratic form or very much so

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm sorry I earlier forgot about your comment to me. However, I've now taken a brief look through the posts in that AoPS thread. Like yourself, I also don't offhand see anything which I would consider to be a complete and robust solution. Regarding "mkh's solution", I assume you mean mkhayech and their post #$9$. If so, I agree it has several issues, such as those you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a straightforward solution. Note that you don’t need to do anything complicated with periodicity nor show the general Cauchy equation.

Letting $x=y=0$ gives $f(0)=0$.

First let’s restrict to considering $g(x)=|f(x)|$.

Let’s show by induction that $g(ky)=kg(y)$ for all nonnegative integer $k$. We already have $k=0$ and $k=1$. Letting $x=ky$ for $k\geq 2$ and applying the inductive hypothesis to $k$ and $k-1$ gives $g((k+1)y)^2=(k-1)^2f(y)+4kf(y)^2=(k+1)^2g(y)^2$, so $g((k+1)y)=(k+1)g(y)$ as desired.

Thus, for all positive rational $r=m/n$, $ g(ry)=g((m/n)y)=mg(y/n)=m/n g(y)=r g(y)$.

Thus, for all positive rational $r$, $g(r)=rg(1)$, so letting $f(1)=c,g(1)=|c|$ gives that $g$ satisfies $g(x)=|cx|$ for all positive rational $x$. Using the continuity of $g$ and the density of the positive rational numbers over the positive reals gives that $|f(x)|=g(x)=|cx|$ for all positive $x$.

If $c=0$, then $f(x)=0=cx$ for all positive $x$. Otherwise, consider $f(x)/(cx)$ for positive $x$. It is always either $1$ or $-1$, it is continuous, and it is 1 at 1 so it must be constantly 1, thus, $f(x)=cx$ for positive $x$.

Now, let’s resolve the negatives.

Substituting $(y,y)$ and $(y,-y)$ gives that $4f(y)f(y)=f(2y)^2-f(0)^2=-4f(y)f(-y)$, so $f(y)(f(y)+f(-y))=0$. Negating $y$ and adding the two equations gives that $(f(y)+f(-y))^2=0$,  so $f(y)=-f(y)$. This holds for all $y$, so $f$ is odd.

Thus, for all positive $x$, $f(-x)=-f(x)=-cx=c(-x)$, so $f(y)=c y$ holds for all $y$, so all solutions are of this form.  Substituting this general equation satisfies the original expression, so all equations of this form are solutions.

Comment: Yeah, I messed some of it up. I just added your comments and cleaned it up a bit.